# How to use SFINAE to enable a certain std::initializer_list constructor only for suitable types

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

Below you find a stripped down, reproducible example of what I'm trying to accomplish. My use-case is a custom container class template. The class has a constructor, taking a `std::initializer_list` of the element type. For the case that the container holds elements of the type `std::unique_ptr<OwnedType>`, I want to enable a further constructor that takes a `std::initialiser_list<typename std::unique_ptr<OwnedType>::pointer>` aka `std::initializer_list<OwnedType*>`. My approach was to use SFINAE to disable that constructor in case that the element type of my container class has no type named `pointer`, which should be a valid SFINAE failure case and no compile error according to my understanding of the examples listed under [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct MyVector
{
    /** General initializer list constructor */
    MyVector (std::initializer_list<T> il) : vector (il) {}

    /** Constructor for the case MyVector<std::unique_ptr<SomeType>>. 
        Should be treated as an SFINAE failure for non unique_ptr types 
    */
    template <typename OwnedTypePtr = typename T::pointer>
    MyVector (std::initializer_list<OwnedTypePtr> il)
    {
        vector.reserve (il.size());
        for (auto* ptr : il)
            vector.emplace_back (ptr);
    }

    std::vector<T> vector;
};

template <typename T>
using UniqueVector = MyVector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;

int main()
{
    UniqueVector<int> uv { new int (0), new int (1), new int (2) };
    MyVector<int> v { 0, 1, 2 };

    return 0;
}
```

(Fails to compile when using clang 10.0.0 on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/Y14rx6))

It seems that I'm understanding something wrong here, as clang complains that

```
type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
in instantiation of template class 'MyVector<int>' requested here
    MyVector<int> v { 0, 1, 2 };
```

So what I expected to be a valid SFINAE failure case is instead interpreted as a compile error. I'm interested why the code above is no valid SFINAE construct and a solution on how to do it right.

=====================================================================

Edit: The Initial question could be solved by the answer given by @super. Unfortunately, now in my real world scenario I run into problems with vectors of `std::complex` values, initialised by scalar values, which worked before these changes. Adjusted example

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <complex>

template <typename T>
struct MyVector
{
    /** General initializer list constructor */
    MyVector (std::initializer_list<T> il) : vector (il) {}

    /** Constructor for the case MyVector<std::unique_ptr<SomeType>>. 
        Should be treated as an SFINAE failure for non unique_ptr types 
    */
    template <typename U = T, typename OwnedTypePtr = typename U::pointer>
    MyVector (std::initializer_list<OwnedTypePtr> il)
    {
        vector.reserve (il.size());
        for (auto* ptr : il)
            vector.emplace_back (ptr);
    }

    std::vector<T> vector;
};

template <typename T>
using UniqueVector = MyVector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;

int main()
{
    UniqueVector<int> uv { new int (0), new int (1), new int (2) };
    MyVector<std::complex<int>> v { 0, 1, 2 };

    return 0;
}
```

[live demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EYhs6e)

I cannot understand why the compiler choses the new unique ptr overload here, as to my knowledge, `std::complex` has no public type named `pointer`.

Comment: Putting a `unique_ptr` in an `initializer_list` is pointless, since you only have `const` access to its members; you can't move from them.

Comment: I'm not trying to put the `unique_ptr` in the `initializer_list`, I'm trying to put a pointer to the underlying type of the `unique_ptr` into the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing one detail.

SFINAE is only possible on the immediate context, which does not include the template parameters from the class. Only the template parameter from the method.

One way of solving this is to use an extra template parameter in the method, that default to `T`.

```
template <typename U = T, typename OwnedTypePtr = typename U::pointer>
MyVector (std::initializer_list<typename U::pointer> il)
{
    vector.reserve (il.size());
    for (auto* ptr : il)
        vector.emplace_back (ptr);
}
```

Here SFINAE will kick in when we use `U` in an invalid way.

Comment: Thanks – totally overlooked that. While this works on the first glance, I'm now getting trouble with T=std::complex<int>. https://godbolt.org/z/Wo7qG1 Edited my original post according to that

Comment: @PluginPenguin Ah, yes. We can't use `OwnedTypePtr` in the parameter since that will enable deduction of what we pass in and in that case the default value for the template parameter is ignored. If we replace it with `typename U::pointer` instead we get the correct behaviour. This is one of the reasons I normally use non-type template parameters to do SFINAE on. It's even required if we want to overload several template constructors with different SFINAE. Gets a little bit more verbose though.

Comment: Aaaah, of course, I see... this totally makes sense.